# Triggering an Azure Devops pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having problems triggering a pipeline from another Pipeline in Azure DevOps. I have a CI pipeline and I want to trigger a Deploy Pipeline whenever CI passes on a master branch. This seems to be *technically* possible, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers) is unclear.

I see the following:

```
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib
    source: security-lib-ci
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

But it's unclear as to a) whether this goes in the triggering pipeline (in my case the CI pipeline) or the triggered pipeline (in my case, the deploy pipeline).

It's also unclear as to what the `pipeline` and `source` refer to, and how I find out these variables? Are they both the name of the pipeline? I've tried various different permutations and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: did my answer helped you? it does answer all your questions... If so, please accept it :)

Comment: Would be really cool if you would make your contribution to the community @Pezholio and mark my solution as valid, since it clearly answers your query. SO is not only to ask questions and get answers in return....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Finally Microsoft has improved their documentation with regards to the pipeline triggers in YAML! Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops).

**EDIT**

After having written my answer, Microsoft has come up with another solution to solve this problem, by using a build completion trigger via a classic pipeline. Their solution can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers-classic?view=azure-devops).

---

---

If you're not publishing an artifact from the triggering pipeline, it won't trigger the triggered pipeline.

Also, there is a very big restriction on the use of these types of triggers. It is necessary to change the `defaultBranch for manual and scheduled builds` in the `depends` pipeline, to the working branch. Otherwise it won't kick in at the end of the `source` pipeline execution. So, let's say you're working on `feature` branch, and `defaultBranch` is set to `feature`. You commit your code, and everything will run as expected: the `source` pipeline kicks in, and at its end, the `depends` pipeline will be triggered. All good! But when you will merge into `master`, if you do not change the `defaultBranch`, the `depends` pipeline won't be triggered at the end of the `source` pipeline. I explain how to change the `defaultBranch` at the end of the answer.

---

## How to setup a pipeline trigger

I managed to get this up and running on a minimalistic project. [Here](https://github.com/binte/Pipelining) you can have the code and [here](https://dev.azure.com/Coutinhos/Pipelining) the project on Azure DevOps. I will try to guide you through how I did it, and answer the questions you've asked in your post.

I will be calling the triggered pipeline as `depends` pipeline and the triggering pipeline as `source` pipeline.

On the `source` pipeline, there's no need to do anything **except** publishing an artifact. If you don't publish an artifact from the `source` pipeline, it won't work. Below you can find the code I am using for my dummy `source` pipeline. I want it to be triggered for `master` branch, and at the end I want to be sure to publish an artifact.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: # branch names which will trigger a build
    - master
pr: none

steps:
  # required to cause pipeline triggering downstream
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.yml
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifactName: dummy-$(Build.BuildId)
```

On the `depends` pipeline (code shown below), I have to disable `CI` and `PR` triggers, otherwise when I commit to this repo, this pipeline will be triggered by the `CI` trigger, and then by the end of the execution of the `source` pipeline. This is done by the two first lines of my code. Then I want that the pipeline named `source` (this is the `source` property in the YAML below), within the project named `Pipelining` (`project` property in the YAML) will trigger the current (`depends`) pipeline when this updates `master` branch.

```
trigger: none
pr: none
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - master
steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: echo 'triggered depends'
```

Does it make sense? It is important for your project name on Azure DevOps to match the `property` in the YAML `depends` pipeline code.For me it is `Pipelining`

[image]

As well as the `source` property, again in the YAML `depends` pipeline code.

[image]

---

## Change the `default` branch

In order to change the `defaultBranch`, because of the issue mentioned above, you should edit the pipeline (in this case, the `depends` pipeline), then on the three dots on the top right corner pick `Triggers`. Then choose the `YAML` tab, and you will get to the screen shown in the image below, where you can set the working branch.

[image]

Comment: For me, it even worked without publishing artifacts

Comment: When I had set this up, it was not working for me without that part @MarkusHartmair. Maybe Microsoft improved it :)

Comment: When i was debugging a similar pipeline dependency trigger chain, i got very little output because the pipeline being triggered was on a different branch (default branch): `/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: ...): Unexpected value 'trigger'` and `/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: ...): Unexpected value 'variables'`. No logs no debug traces. Hope this helps others.

Comment: @ccoutinho: Very helpful, thank you. Any idea on how to define all/multiple source pipelines in the depends yaml? Do we need to define them all or is there a way to define any pipeline? E.g. to have a java default pipeline which does some maven thing when any java project (repo) receives a merge.

Comment: @MyName I haven't done that before, but I assume you need to declare them all

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the pipeline that triggers (source) does not specify any details of the pipeline to be triggered (depends)? What if I have a pipeline that does something generic and want it to be triggered by multiple pipelines, and based on its output, the triggering pipeline will continue executing or fail.

Example (source) builds and unit tests (depends) runs E2E tests. Based on my (depends) results, I want (source) to go to the next stage or fail. 

If I have other pipelines like (sourc2, source3, source4) they could also use (depends) and its output. Is this possible?

Comment: You can definitely have multiple pipelines bring triggered from a single source pipeline. But I am 99% sure you can't have a stage in source pipeline triggering a depends pipeline, and then depends pipeline triggering a second stage in the source pipeline : source pipeline will trigger depends pipeline on successful conclusion, hence what you are trying to achieve does not seem possible. And that setup seems not only overcomplicated, but also not ideal. You don't want to have A depending on B, and B depending on A. Or source depending on depends, and depends depending on source

Comment: I forked your repo and made 2 pipelines one for source and one for depends using existing azure devops yaml file, and ensured the default branch is set to master. Then manually ran source pipeline, but it did not trigger depends. Would be useful if you can provide others with a recipe on how to reproduce this on their own. 
For me, this does not work without adding a build completion trigger (by going to Triggers, and not in the yaml file)

Comment: Did you set the default branch in the depends pipeline? Were you able to see the published artifact after running the source pipeline? If yes, can you run it again, but without manually triggering? The build completion trigger feature you mentioned is a new thing, it was not available when I implemented my solution. I will add it to my answer, thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: Yes, I set the default branch in the depends pipeline to the master as you suggested. I was also able to see the published artifacts after running the source pipeline. I ran the source pipeline both manually and by pushing some changes. But in all cases the depends was not triggered untilI added a build completion trigger as Microsoft suggest here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers-classic?view=azure-devops

Comment: But could not get the depends to trigger on completion of source by only depending on yaml file, as described by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops
Seems to me like this feature Microsoft has made is only useful for filtering incoming triggers (which in this case would be a build completion trigger set up in classic way, meaning through UI but not yaml file)

Comment: Hi @masih! I thought that MS might have introduced a bug, so I gave it a try in my demo repository without any changes and everything worked like a charm. 

I would suggest you to redo everything from scratch, you might be missing something! Please have a look in the azure DevOps project for confirmation: https://dev.azure.com/Coutinhos/Pipelining

Both manually triggering the source pipeline, and committing new changes to the master branch, triggered the depends pipeline

Comment: Have you properly referenced the Azure DevOps project in which you have the code?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling across a somewhat related problem in 2024 and beyond:

You could also use the `az` command line tool and the built-in Access Token, when you need to trigger a pipeline inside Azure DevOps on the same Organization.

```yaml
- job:
  displayName: "Run Pipeline"
  steps:
  - bash: |
      az pipelines run --project 'PROJECT' --id 123456 --branch 'main' 
    displayName: 'Trigger Pipeline 123456'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

`az pipelines run` can also set parameters for a pipeline you want to trigger:
`az pipelines run --project 'PROJECT' --id 123456 --branch 'main' --parameters 'param1=VALUE'`
(The ones when you click "Run Pipeline" and can set/select in the UI in the Browser)
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run

To find the ID of a pipeline:
`az pipelines list -p "ProjectName" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property Id, Name, queueStatus | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "PipelineName" }`

Comment: I like this better than a lot of the other convoluted duct tape and string that seem to be required by previous configurations.  Much more direct and useful.

Answer (score 2):

Above yaml pipeline trigger should be defined in the triggered pipeline(deploy pipeline).

`- pipeline: string` the string here is identifier you give to this pipeline resource. It can any string.

`source: string` the string here is the definition name of the triggering pipeline(the name of your CI pipeline).

Below yaml is from the document [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource).

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: string  # identifier for the pipeline resource
    project:  string # project for the build pipeline; optional input for current project
    source: string  # source pipeline definition name
    branch: string  # branch to pick the artifact, optional; defaults to all branches
    version: string # pipeline run number to pick artifact, optional; defaults to last successfully completed run
    trigger:     # optional; triggers are not enabled by default.
      branches:
        include: [string] # branches to consider the trigger events, optional; defaults to all branches.
        exclude: [string] # branches to discard the trigger events, optional; defaults to none.
```

**Option**: You can also set the pipeline triggers from Ui page. Go the edit page of the triggered yaml pipeline(Deploy pipeline), Click the **3dots** and choose **Triggers**

[image]

Go to Triggers--> Build completion and click add--> Select your triggering pipeline(CI pipeline)

[image]

Update:

I saw the pipeline resource in azure-deploy.yml is defined as below.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'Deploy to Development'
    source: 'DFE-Digital.dfe-teachers-payment-service'
  trigger:
    branches:
      include:
      - "master"
      - "release-stuff"
```

please try changing the indentation of **trigger** element the same as **source** element. Check below example:

```
    resources:
      pipelines:
      - pipeline: 'Deploy to Development'
        source: 'DFE-Digital.dfe-teachers-payment-service'
        trigger:
          branches:
            include:
            - "master"
            - "release-stuff"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't working for me (I'd rather not try the UI option as I'd rather keep everything documented through code). My CI pipeline is called `DFE-Digital.dfe-teachers-payment-service` and my deploy pipeline is called `Deploy to Development`, so I set the `pipeline` variable to `Deploy to Development` and the `source` variable to `DFE-Digital.dfe-teachers-payment-service`. I expect the deploy pipeline to kick off when the CI finishes, but nothing happens.

Comment: In desperation, I've also tried the UI option, and that doesn't work either

Comment: The repo is open, so you can see my YAML here https://github.com/DFE-Digital/dfe-teachers-payment-service/blob/release-stuff/azure-deploy.yml

Comment: I saw there is an indent error for trigger element in your azure-deploy.yml.  Please check above update.

Comment: Did you create a pipeline in azure devops pipeline for yaml azure-deploy.yml. It needs to be added as a pipeline in azure devops pipeline.

Comment: I've created a pipeline, yep. Running the suggestion gives me the error `/azure-deploy.yml: (Line: 13, Col: 3, Idx: 127) - (Line: 13, Col: 3, Idx: 127): While parsing a block collection, did not find expected '-' indicator.`

Comment: I copied the contents in azure-deploy.yml and created a test pipeline. It didnot reproduce above error. Could you share the pipeline you created on azure devops.

Comment: It's a private pipeline, so I don't think I'll be able to, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

I may assume you are not working on the master branch, right? I have the same issue previously. But after I read the section Default branch for triggers of [MS's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema). I understand why. The trigger only examine master's branch's yaml file by default. This means the pipeline will only be triggered by the definition of triggers in master branch's yaml file.

Therefore, whatever branches you add in the trigger section of yaml file in other branches(not master), tirgger is not active. You need to change the pipeline to look the yaml file in your current branch, not master. Just follow the doc's instruction, change the default trigger branch. You will get it working.

Once you merge your work into master, you probably need to change the dedault trigger branch back to master.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following:

- In source pipeline I didn't need to create an artifact
- In depends pipeline if I wanted to build after any commit to the source branch I could get it to work with this:

```
    trigger: none
    pr: none
    resources:
          pipelines:
          - pipeline: 'depends'
            source: 'common-gulp-trigger'
            trigger: true
```